# Is my iPhone locked with iCloud or not? I don't have SIM Card yet

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, activation-lock

I bought an iPhone 5C from a friend and I'm not sure if it's Activation Locked or not and I don't have a SIM card yet. He hasn't used it and didn't know anything about that, he got it second hand.

When I got the phone it was stuck at the lock screen because of too many password attempts. I've put it in restore mode, and now the phone is "formated/restored"

When turning the phone back on, it first asks my country, then it wants me to connect to Wi-Fi, which I do, and next it says I need to put a SIM card (not pin-locked) in.

If the iPhone was Activation locked, does it ask for the Apple ID after you connect to Wi-Fi or after you put a SIM card in?

Can you provide a step-by-step guide?

Comment: So i want to hear some1 who have icloud locked iphone, and tried it first without sim-card. 1st it asks language, then wants you to connect wifi, whats then? do it ask id/password for icloud or do it asks sim-card. for me it asks sim-card. when i buy new nano sim-card do i have that risk i install in and it asks me icloud?

Comment: If you can't get to the step where it lets you enter your Apple ID of choice, you can't be sure it's not still locked.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest manner to check is from this web site:

- https://www.icloud.com/activationlock/

If that fails, the older method still works in all cases and Apple describes the steps here:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5818

Expand the portion that says (in the english version) **How do I check for Activation Lock before purchasing a used device?**

It states:

> Follow each of these steps to make sure that you can use the device
>   you purchase:
>
> Turn the device on and slide to unlock. If the passcode lock screen or
>   the home screen appears, the device has not been erased. Ask the
>   seller to completely erase the device by going to Settings > General >
>   Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. Do not take ownership of any
>   used iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch until it has been erased.
>
> Begin the device setup process. After choosing a language, choosing a
>   country, and connecting to a network, the device will begin
>   activation. If you are asked for the previous owner’s Apple ID and
>   password, the device is still linked to their account. Hand the device
>   back to the seller and ask them to enter their password.

On iOS 7, the part where you are asked if you want to enter your Apple ID is the step that means it's not locked to another iCloud account. If you cannot enter your new Apple ID from the setup you will see a prompt to enter an existing password and can conclude that it's not released from the previous owner.

Since you're not getting to that step, either get a SIM card that satisfied the carrier lock on that device or perhaps connect it to iTunes and see if you can restore the device. In my experience, iTunes also checks if the device is locked and will tell you to remove the iCloud lock before it lets you restore the device when it's at the point where you can start the setup assistant.

Comment: I restored my phone succesfully with itunes yes, so maybe my phone is not locked and i dont have to worry getting new sim-card in?

Comment: Ohh yeah thanks for apple site link i read there is: "After choosing a language, choosing a country, and connecting to a network, the device will begin activation. If you are asked for the previous owner’s Apple ID and password, the device is still linked to their account. "

Comment: Yes - I would say you're probably safe if you got a good restore without needing a jailbreak and could enter your Apple ID into the restored phone.